# Angular not adding comment to scope

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm trying to add a comment and push it within myposts array

i can successfully make a post but i get an network error when i try to add a comment.

this is the error i get, not sure why its not working.

> {"message":"The given data was
>   invalid.","errors":{"comment_body":["The comment body field is
>   required."]}}

**CommentController**

```
public function create(Request $request, Post $post)
{

    $data = request()->validate([
     'comment_body' => 'required|max:1000'
    ]);


    $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
    $data['name'] = auth()->user()->name;

    $post = Comment::create($data);
    $data['id'] = $post->id;
    $data['created_at'] = $post->created_at->diffForHumans();

    $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

    if(!$response){
        return 'something went wrong';
    }

    return response()->json($data); 


}
```

**main.js**

```
$scope.myposts = [];



$scope.addPost = function(){    
    $http.post('/auth/post', {
        body: $scope.post.body, 
    }).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);  
        data.data['user'] = {
            name: data.data.name
        },



        $scope.myposts.push(data.data);

    });

    $scope.post.body = '';
};

$scope.addComment = function(){

    $http.post('/post/comment',{
        comment_body: $scope.post.comment_body,
    }).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $scope.myposts.push(result.data);

    });



};
```

**html**

```
 <div id="mypost" class="col-md-10 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts  ">
                <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><a class="link_profile" href="/profile/<% post.user.name | lowercase %>"><% post.user.name %></a></div>
                <div class="panel-body panel" ng-init="getLikeText(post); getLikecount(post)">  


                <i style="color:tomato; float:right; font-size:24px;" ng-click="like(post); toggle = !toggle" 
                ng-class="{[noheart] : !post.likedByMe, [heart]: post.likedByMe }">
                    <h3 style="font-size:20px; margin:20px 0px; text-align:center;"  ng-bind="post.likesCount">   </h3>
                </i>


                    <figure>
                        <p class="mybody2" ng-model="post.body" editable-text="post.body" e-form="textBtnForm"> <% post.body %></p>
                        <p name="post.created_at" ><% post.createdAt %> </p>
                    </figure>
                    <span>

                     <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)" ng-if="post.deletable"></i>


                          <button ng-if="post.update" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()" ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible">
                            Edit
                          </button>

                        <span><button ng-if="post.update" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updatePost(post)">Update</button></span>
                    </span>
                    <hr>
                    <span class="toggle-comments">
                        <a ng-show="post.comments.length !== 0"  ng-click="comments = !comments" > View Comments</a>
                        <a ng-click="writecomment =! writecomment"> Write A Comment </a>
                    </span>
                </div>


                <div ng-show="comments" id="comments" class="col-md-offset-2  panel-default" ng-repeat="comment in post.comments"> 
                    <div style="font-size:10px;" id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading">
                        <h6><% comment.user.name %><h6>
                    </div>
                    <figure>
                        <p style="padding:10px; min-height:50px; word-wrap:break-word;"> <% comment.comment_body%></p>
                    </figure>

                </div>


                 <div class="comment-class animated bounceInUp" ng-show="writecomment">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form ng-model="postForm" name="postform" method="POST" novalidate>
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="comment.title">Write a Comment</label>
                                <textarea ng-model="comment.body" type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="" cols="2" rows="2"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <button id="eli-style-button" ng-click="addComment()" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
```

Comment: Your `ng-model` is `comment_body` but you are trying to send `post.comment_body`

Comment: $scope.comment.body seems to be working i think there is an issue with my html

i will update it

Comment: @BARNOWL can you tell me? which version of `laravel` you are using. and I have got the solution for `laravel 5.4`

Comment: @chintankotadiya we fixed this. thank you  laravel 5.5

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620996/integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-post-id-cannot-be-null/47621127?noredirect=1#comment82200952_47621127

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending comment_body data to server, first you need to change the ng-model in textarea from ng-model="comment_body" to ng-model="post.comment_body", then,to have a nice user experience;  you need to do some validation in client side, like the example code, finally you should handle the reject in the promise when try to save de data.

```js
$scope.addComment = function(){

    $http.post('/post/comment',{
        comment_body: $scope.post.comment_body,
    }).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $scope.myposts.push(result.data);

    }, function(error){
      // do somethig with server error
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });



};
```

```html
<form name="postform" method="POST" novalidate>
 {{ csrf_field() }}
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment.title">Write a Comment</label>
  <textarea 
  ng-required="true"
  ng-model="post.comment_body" class="form-control" name="comment_body" id="" cols="2" rows="2"></textarea>
  <p ng-if="postform.$dirty && postform.comment_body.$invalid }">Required</p>
 </div>
 <button id="eli-style-button" ng-disabled="postform.$invalid" ng-click="addComment()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope this help you

Comment: i get this

`Cannot read property 'comment_body' of undefined` i think i know why its not working

its my html setup, i updated the code let me know your thoughts

Comment: $scope.comment.body  seems to work but the thing is, this is form is within a ng-repeat, i can see the information being passed in the network tab

Comment: yes, you need to initialize the $scope.post, something like this,  $scope.post  = {} or  $scope.post= {comment_body: "" }

Comment: post is used as `post in myposts` so there is a conflict

Comment: you have an updated way to go about this, im not understanding the $scope.post = {}, do i put that in the js script

Comment: you have a comment form by each post?

Comment: when i take the from outside of the ng-repeat="post in myposts" it works but when its inside the repeat it does not, im styling it accordingly and want to keep the form in place

Comment: yes that is correct give me one sec let me show u what i got

Comment: (sdsd, 1, BarnOwl, 2017-12-02 22:26:57, 2017-12-02 22:26:57)) this indicates that it works

Comment: but i had to take the form out of the ng-repeat="post in myposts" in order for it to work

Comment: but i need it to stay in the ng-repeat, sorry if im not making sense

Comment: `Cannot read property 'comment' of undefined` when it is inside of ng-repeat

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/geuwyu43/1/, you can see a form inside a ng--repeat with validation, of course each item in posts array can't be null

Comment: I know, is just a snapshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160354/discussion-between-dave008-and-barnowl).