# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post_id' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.5 and im trying  to add a comment to a post and i get the following error when i submit to the form

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'post_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `comments` (`comment_body`,
>   `user_id`, `post_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sdsd, 1, ,
>   2017-12-03 12:29:58, 2017-12-03 12:29:58))

im going to be using: `<% %>` is for angular, just letting everyone know.

In tinker this works

```
 Comment::create(['comment_body' => 'this works', 'user_id'=> 1, 'post_id'=>8]);
```

**Route*

```
Route::post('post/comment', 'CommentController@create');
```

**Post Model**

```
use App\User;
use App\Like;
use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class Post extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body',
        'user_id',
        'created_at',

    ];

   public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function likes()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'comment_body',
        'user_id',
        'post_id'

    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

**CommentConroller**

```
public function create(Request $request, Post $post)
{

    $data = request()->validate([
     'comment_body' => 'required|max:1000'
    ]);


    $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
    $data['name'] = auth()->user()->name;
    $data['post_id'] = $post->id;
    $post = Comment::create($data);



    $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

    if(!$response){
        return 'something went wrong';
    }

    return response()->json($data); 


}
```

**Html**

```
  <div class="comment-class animated bounceInUp" ng-show="writecomment">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ng-form ng-model="commentForm" name="commentForm" method="POST" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Write a Comment</label>


                            <textarea ng-model="post.comment" type="text" class="form-control" name="comment_body" cols="2" rows="2"></textarea>
                        </div>
                       <button id="eli-style-button" ng-click="addComment(post)" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
        <!-- END Comment form Inside Ng-repeat -->
                </div>
            <!-- End of ng-repeat post in mypost -->
            </div>
```

**Main.js**

```
$scope.addComment = function(post){

    $http.post('/post/comment',{
        comment_body: post.comment,
    }).then(function(result){
        console.log(result.data);
        $scope.myposts.push(result.data);
    });
};
```

Comment: In your CommentController, it looks like you’re only using $post to get the ID. Have you made sure that your Type-hinting is actually getting the Post? Because you do not have a parameter set for it in your routes file, nor does it appear you are passing Post into your http request in the Ajax function.

Comment: type hinting what is that ? 

im going to try to do

   
        `$post = Comment::create($data);`
        `$data['post_id'] = $post->id;`

Comment: Check that your $post parameter is actually being set.

Comment: i did this in tinker `Comment::create(['comment_body' => 'this works', 'user_id'=> 1, 'post_id'=>8]);`

and it works

Comment: Right, but here you are MANUALLY ensuring that 'post_id' has a value. There is no problem with the Model::create function. It appears evident that you are simply not passing in your $post parameter correctly. Remove `Post $post`, and pass the post id in with your `comment_body` in your Ajax call.

Comment: Request $request, $post is in my scope, im seeing the post id in the url, were getting closer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding), you have to include the post as a parameter in your route:

```
Route::post('post/{post}/comment', 'CommentController@create');
```

Then call it like this:

```
 $http.post('/post/' + post.id + '/comment' ...
```

Right now in your controller you are getting an empty Post instance that has no ID.

Comment: let me test it and i got some questions on why must this be, because when i orginally add a post using angular, i dont have to pass a post in the rouute, one sec

Comment: @BARNOWL You only need to provide the post ID if you are modifying or accessing an existing post. When creating a new post there is no existing post to bind to your route. When you edit a post or add a comment to a post Laravel needs to know which post you are referring to so it must be provided in the route (or alternatively you can provide it in the post body and fetch the Post instance manually).

Comment: were getting closer, im getting `Trying to get property of non-object` let me fix this one sec were getting closer

Comment: thanks for your explaination, we fixed it ` $data['post_id'] = $post;`

Comment: @BARNOWL That may work, but it seems like something is still wrong. $post should be a Post instance. Make sure that the route parameter name matches the model name exactly (ie if the model is Post, the route should be 'post/{post}/comment'

Comment: Hi, mathew i am also getting this ind of error , "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048" . In the model i  have given   protected $fillable = ['title', 'module_description','module_link']; , in the controller i have made title mandatory so when i submit the form without module_description and link this error occurs . what have to done.